# webpack-dev-middleware post request error (vue-cli)

Tags: express, iframe, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-middleware

I'm writing OPA for some existing service using vue-cli and web pack template. Parent service loading app in iframe and gives it api access via postMessage. However in first open it seems to post some auth data which I don't need in my case, so when i'm opening in iframe my dev-server express gives me 404 "Can't POST /".

Is there a way to allow POST request on my index.html?

Comment: I found the only way to redirect post requests on express. 

app.post('*', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});

in dev-server.js